# Spring MVC / AbstractExcelView / Apache POI : File Error

Tags: spring, excel, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI and extending Springs AbstractExcelView to create Excel sheets.

```
public class ExcelSpreadsheetView extends AbstractExcelView {

protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
            HSSFWorkbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

//GET POSITIONS TO LOOP THROUGH FROM MODEL
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Position> positions = (List<Position>) model.get("positions");

int lastRow = 0;

mySheet = wb.createSheet("SHEET1");

myRow = mySheet.createRow(lastRow);
myCell = myRow.createCell(0);

//loop through positions
for (int p = 0; p < positions.size(); p++) {
     myRow = mySheet.createRow(lastRow);
     myCell = myRow.createCell(0);
     myCell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(positions.get(p).getPositionName()));
     lastRow++;
}

//response stuff goes here, but I shouldnt need it

}
```

I can successfully create a sheet when I have the following code after all the POI code:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"spreadsheet.xls\"");
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
wb.write(out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Thing is, in none of the examples online do people include the writing out to the OutputStream or setting the ContentType, it seems like the AbstractExcelView handles that.

When I comment out the 6 lines above, it tries to create the file (I can see in console logs that its parsing all the data correctly), but when I go to open the file, Excel fails to open it and displays the following:

"File Error: data may have been lost."

I know my code works as is, I'm just trying to do it the right way and follow what everyone else is doing online.  I don't think I have code in the OutputStream  or ContentType stuff, but it only works if I do.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Show me more code please.

You use HSSFSheet ?

```
public class ExcelReportView extends AbstractExcelView {
    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, HSSFWorkbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        // create a wordsheet
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Title");

        HSSFRow header = sheet.createRow(0);
        header.createCell(0).setCellValue("whatever");
        header.createCell(1).setCellValue("whatever");

        int rowNum = 1;
        for (...) {
            // create the row data
            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue("whatever");
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue("whatever");
        }
    }
}
```